# Conditional join on soonest date - SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with two tables:

**tblOrders**

```
| Part | Order |
|:----:|:-----:|
| AXXA | 10122 |
| AXXA | 10125 |
| AXXB | 10244 |
| AXXB | 10254 |
| AXXB | 10259 |
```

and **tblPOs**

```
| rOrder |  PONum  |   PODate   |
|:------:|:-------:|:----------:|
|  10122 | PO99283 |  2/6/2020  |
|  10125 | PO99283 |  2/6/2020  |
|  10244 | PO99455 |  3/22/2020 |
|  10244 | PO99456 |  3/11/2020 |
|  10254 | PO99019 |  1/22/2020 |
|  10259 | PO99122 | 12/22/2020 |
|  10259 | PO99122 |  1/2/2021  |
```

I am trying to join these two tables, and for each order, select the PO with the earliest arrival date (in the event there is more than one).

So for Order Number `10244`, it has two POs, `PO99455` and `PO99456`. I would want `PO99456` to be associated, since it's date of `03/11/2020` is sooner than `PO99455`'s date of `03/22/2020`.

An ideal resulting dataset would look like:

```
| PartNum | OrderNum |  PONum  |   PODate   |
|:-------:|:--------:|:-------:|:----------:|
|   AXXA  |   10122  | PO99283 |  2/6/2020  |
|   AXXA  |   10125  | PO99283 |  2/6/2020  |
|   AXXB  |   10244  | PO99456 |  3/11/2020 |
|   AXXB  |   10254  | PO99019 |  1/22/2020 |
|   AXXB  |   10259  | PO99122 | 12/22/2020 |
```

Currently, I have written:

```
SELECT
  a.PartNum,
  a.OrderNum,
  b.PONum,
  MAX(b.PODate) AS PODate

FROM
  tblOrders a
    LEFT JOIN tblPOs b ON a.OrderNum = b.rOrderNum

GROUP BY
  a.PartNum,
  a.OrderNum,
  b.PONum
```

Which yields:

```
PartNum     OrderNum    PONum   PODate
AXXA    10122   PO99283     2020-02-05
AXXA    10125   PO99283     2020-02-05
AXXB    10244   PO99455     2020-03-21
AXXB    10244   PO99456     2020-03-10
AXXB    10254   PO99019     2020-01-21
AXXB    10259   PO99122     2021-01-01
```

I've set up a [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1fbfc/2) with this demo. How can I change my query to achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT o.*, po.*
FROM tblOrders o OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) po.*
      FROM tblPOs p
      WHERE p.OrderNum = o.rOrderNum
      ORDER BY PODate ASC
     ) po
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to join against the earliest related row.

For example:

```
select
  o.part as partnum,
  o.order as ordernum,
  lp.ponum,
  lp.podate  
from tblorders o
left join (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by rorder order by podate) as rn
  from tblpos
) lp on lp.rorder = o.order and lp.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this window function

```
SELECT PartNum,
       OrderNum,
       PONum,
       PODate
FROM   (
          SELECT   o.PartNum,
                   o.OrderNum,
                   p.PONum,
                   p.PODate,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.rOrderNum ORDER BY PODate) AS RowN
          FROM     tblOrders o
                   JOIN tblPOs p 
                       ON o.OrderNum = P.rOrderNum
       ) a
WHERE   RowN = 1
```